# Assets precompile not working after upgrade from Rails 2 to Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, compass-sass

After upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3, I get the following error when I run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`:

```
rake aborted!
Undefined mixin 'linear-gradient'.
```

config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

config/environments/production.rb:

```
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest = true
```

Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem "compass-rails"
```

config/compass.rb:

```
project_type = :rails
project_path = Compass::AppIntegration::Rails.root
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "public"
sass_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets"
environment = Compass::AppIntegration::Rails.env
```

When I try to compile the assets with `bundle exec compass compile` it runs without any errors. Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: i think the error is in your css file. it can not find your mixin.

Comment: I have debug the code and this line give me error
@include linear-gradient(color-stops(#b2a289,#9c907a), left);
this file provide by compass gem i think the above code works in rails2 application

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add the following line to `application.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile << /(^[^_]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
```

Comment: Thanx to reply I already try it, and it does not work for me.